# Curl doesn't download all the records from the website

Tags: api, pagination, ringcentral

Using the API to download the companies' complete call log.  The documentation states that to download all without pagination to list 0 for number of records per page. This does not work for me.  What am I doing wrong?

Tried 0

```
curl --request GET \
  --url 'https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/~/call-log?view=Simple&dateFrom=2019-07-26&dateTo=2019-07-28&page=1&perPage=0' \
  --header 'accept: application/json' \
  --header 'authorization: Bearer <MyToken>'
```

Expected full call log.  Returned only 99 records

Answer (score 4):

As per this link, `"1000 is the max perPage setting. If there are more than 1000 records, you will be able to call the nextPage in a URL that's provided in the API response paging property."`

https://forums.developers.ringcentral.com/questions/329/exporting-call-log-data.html

You can try removing the `page` option
As per this below link the solution to read at once without pagination they suggested is:

- read all extensions under your account.
- read call log of each
  extension one at a time.

ref: https://forums.developers.ringcentral.com/questions/1254/how-to-read-all-users-call-logs-at-once.html

Answer (score 1):

> The documentation states that to download all without pagination to list 0 for number of records per page.

I searched through the [docs](https://developers.ringcentral.com/guide), but couldn't find that line or anything specifically related.

The [API Spec](https://netstorage.ringcentral.com/dpw/api-reference/specs/rc-platform.yml?v=2019072720190715-0339) for the `perPage` query parameter for the current endpoint reads the following:

> ```
> /restapi/v1.0/account/{accountId}/call-log:
>     get:
>       tags:
>       ...
>       parameters:
>       ...
>         - name: perPage
>           in: query
>           description: Indicates the page size (number of items)
>           default: 100
>           required: false
>           type: integer
>       ...
> ```

Though by taking a look at [one of the examples provided](https://ringcentral-tutorials.github.io/calllog-visualization-nodejs-demo/), I assume that to get max logs `perPage` should be set to `1000` and `page` should not be provided as the following function suggest:

```js
function readCallLogs(){
  var configs = {}
  if ($('#phoneNumber').val() != "")
    configs['phoneNumber'] = $('#phoneNumber').val()
  if ($('#extension').val() != "")
    configs['extensionNumber'] = $('#extension').val()

  if ($('#direction').val() != "default")
    configs['direction'] = $('#direction').val()
  if ($('#type').val() != "default")
    configs['type'] = $('#type').val()
  if ($('#transport').val() != "default")
    configs['transport'] = $('#transport').val()

  configs['view'] = $('#view').val()

  configs['showBlocked'] = $('#showBlocked').is(":checked")
  configs['withRecording'] = $('#withRecording').is(":checked")
  configs['dateFrom'] = $("#fromdatepicker").val() + "T00:00:00.000Z"
  configs['dateTo'] = $("#todatepicker").val() + "T23:59:59.999Z"
  configs['perPage'] = 1000

  var url = "readlogs?access=" + $('#access_level').val();
  var posting = $.post( url, configs );
  posting.done(function( response ) {
    var res = JSON.parse(response)
    if (res.hasOwnProperty('calllog_error')){
      alert(res.calllog_error)
    }else{
      callLogsData = new CallLogsData(JSON.parse(response))
      drawGraphs()
    }
  });
  posting.fail(function(response){
    alert(response.statusText);
  });
}
```

Hence you should try editing your initial call to match the following:

```sh
GET /restapi/v1.0/account/~/call-log?view=Simple&dateFrom=2019-07-26&dateTo=2019-07-28&perPage=1000 HTTP/1.1
Host: platform.devtest.ringcentral.com
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer U0pDMDFQMTdQQVMwMHxBQUFBeHFCSjZGR3FSYkNJREcyQUlUNTUyN085b05PZEUza2R4VV9oWjF0ZzhKOUpEekJ4WDU5T2U1czFvSzJ3WGN4NF9QWWRPMEVYNENYQjd4dmJsWHJocGJRcC1BcDlrUHZIczcycTVONm13NDZJSWN6VnZ1YzNsU3NVY2doMnd2UHlCMGxkaC1MTXlfZFk5VS0yZUUtWnpRejhKUXJtT21yMFQ0ZHpKQ1AwbnhfQmRRTTRKazR3OVNuTVE4THNOa3BfcW1oX21mUGtQdWNkUVN4ZnRaUzd8Mkt2
```